# finding the highest match between two images and/or point clouds

Tags: ros, 2d-image, ros-kinetic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

which kind of methods are used for finding the highest match between two images and/or point clouds?
I would be grateful if anybody can support.

ros, kinetic 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390752/finding-the-highest-match-between-two-images-and/or-point-clouds/) by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2021-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best program for matching point clouds that I am aware is: 3DSmoothNet (https://github.com/zgojcic/3DSmoothNet)

It uses a siamese deep learning architecture and fully convolutional layers using a voxelized smoothed density value (SDV) representation with 94%+ matching for rotation invariant point clouds. There is also a very interesting paper, highly recommend to read on the subject. This can be part of your pipeline when processing point clouds from different sources.

One of the things to be aware when using is that both point clouds need to have the same scale, otherwise it will be an issue.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2021-11-12**:
Thanks a lot @osilva,
and do you know what are the requirements for installing this pkg?
and what about images? because I have heard that working with point clouds is really hard, so first I want to start with images. and find the image which has the highest match with the one saved as reference.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-12**:
For images, start with the basics using RANSAC application in homography, perhaps learn with OpenCV first. The video tutorial is for Matlab but you will get the idea: https://ros-developer.com/2017/12/26/finding-homography-matrix-using-singular-value-decomposition-and-ransac-in-opencv-and-matlab/.

Working with pointclouds it's more challenging but it's a very exciting field that merges Computer Vision and Robotics. Hope this is what you were looking for and if so kindly accept the answer.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-12**:
The installation steps for 3DSmoothNet are in the repo but you need to be familiar with deep learning to use it.

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2021-11-12**:
Thanks a lot @osilva
yes, it was the one that i am  searching for

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2021-11-12**:
@osilva, sorry, do you know any reference or link for learning deep learning that explains clearly?

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-12**:
i'd recommend to learn PyTorch or Tensorflow there are many great books. It's a very broad field, specifically for Robotics the area of Reinforcement Learning and Computer Vision with Deep Learning will give you some strong foundation